# php mail() - cannot use email address with underscore character

Tags: php, email

I run a basic test, where user inputs their details through html form, and then php script collects the data and sends it in an email. It's a superbasic script.

Now. This script works, with exception when I use an email with underscore character eg. example_1@yahoo.com . Then it doesn't work + also I get this email address displayed in the browser like

To: example_1@yahoo.com

even though I don't echo this in any way.
Would anyone have an idea what I should modify / add to the code? I read about preg_replace or str_replace, but not sure if this is applicable to this case. Apparently underscore is part of the convention with email, so not sure why this is even a problem.

I add a code as per suggestion:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Form result : </h1> 


<?php
$first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
$second_name = $_POST['secondname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$to = 'example_tur@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'php test';
$message = "Hi $first_name " . "How are you $second_name .";


$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


mail($to, $subject, $message, 'From: ' . $email,  $headers);


echo 'Welcome: ' . $first_name . '<br />';
echo 'Your last name is: ' . $second_name;
echo 'Your email is' . $email;
?>


</body>
</html>
```

and html as requested (pls disregard css)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testphp.css" >
</head>


<body>
<form method="post" action="testphp.php">

<label for="firstname">First name: </label>
<input type ="text" name ="firstname"/>

<br>


<label for="secondname">Second name: </label>
<input type ="text" name ="secondname"/>


<br>

<label for="email">Email: </label>
<input type ="text" name ="email"/>

<br>

<input type ="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start by posting your code. This is far too broad and unclear what you're asking. Plus, you're using a GET method or POST method is omitted from your form. Again, post your code.

Comment: I posted the code. Sorry for the grammar (no spaces etc), I just start wtih PHP.

Comment: You state *"I get this email address displayed in the browser like..."* - that tells me that it's a GET method in your form method. I'll need to see your HTML form too in order to possibly rule that out.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out, just added this

Comment: Ok, this line `mail($to, $subject, $message, 'From: ' . $email,  $headers);` you're not using headers correctly. I suggest you change that to `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` then your headers to 
`$header = "From: ". $first_name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";`

Comment: *sigh* when getting that message, check the *source* in the browser (e.g.: Ctrl+U)

Comment: Hi Fred-ii  - I changed this but it's still the same. I thing you meant $headers not $header in first place.

Comment: @Karoly - yes I check this and it shows  To:example_tur@yahoo.com

Comment: @Turo Yes, `$headers`, my mistake. I forgot to change it, taken from my own script library.

Comment: Yeap I changed this but still did not work